# ImageButton overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout with an inner RelativeLayout. This contains a TextView on the left and an ImageButton (star) on the right.

[image: The whole layout]

As you can see the ImageButton overlapps the text although I'm setting the tags layout_alignEnd and layout_alignRight on the ImageButton.

This is my inner RelativeLayout:

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/star"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to achieve that the text is always on the left of the ImageButton and that the ImageButton never overlapps the text.

What's the problem here?

Comment: use `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_question"` in imagebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `layout_toLeftOf` property in `TextView`

```
 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_favorite"
```

You use `layout_alignParentRight` property in `ImageView`

```
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Just try this

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_topic"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_favorite"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:src="@drawable/star"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make relative to linear, and adjust weights according to your requirement.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="6">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt_favorite"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tv_question"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tv_question"
            android:background="#00ffffff"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you dont need to setup your Textview (tv_question) to 

`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

cause its width is match_parent. So if you wanna let your textview just be next to your imageview, then do this. 
first fix your imageview's position, let's say, align right, and then, let TextView just be left side of imageview

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/bt_favorite"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/star"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_question"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt_favorite"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

finally, you dont have to set your RelativeLayout attr - android:orientation, it doesnt work. 
Try this, it should work.